# Metric Space and Analysis: Prove that if $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$ and $c\in U$, then $U\setminus\{c\}$ is disconnected

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Prove that if $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $c\in U$, then $U\setminus \{c\}$ is disconnected.

Comment: You gotta try something. Removing $c$ splits $\mathbb{R}$ into two obvious subsets.

Comment: If you remove $c$, you get two disjoint subsets, one with elements of $U$ less than $c$, and one with elements of $U$ greater than $c$

Comment: Hi and welcome to math.SE. Please use [MathJax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/570189) to improve readability and increase your chances to get meaningful answers.
Also you're more likely to be well received if you show us your efforts and attempts, instead of merely stating your question.

Comment: @Chen Yingtong First, let U be an open interval, say (a,b). Let c $\in$ (a,b). Now remove c from the interval. What is the resulting set?

Now let U be an arbitrary open set. How did the steps above help you with a more general U?

Answer (score 0):

If you can contain your set into two open disjoint sets, then your set is disconnected.

Think about it.

Are there two disjoint open sets covering $R-{c}?

Answer (score 0):

I offer the following generalization of this statement, which is intended to be a hint as to the direction that will lead you to the solution.

> Suppose that $U$ is a (not necessarily open) subset of $\mathbb R$ and $c\in U$. Suppose, furthermore, that there exist real numbers $a,b\in U$ such that $a<c<b$.
>
> Then, $U\setminus\{c\}$ is disconnected.

To-do list:

- Prove that the highlighted statement is true.
- Show that a non-empty open subset of $\mathbb R$ satisfies the premise of the above statement. Conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = U\cap(-\infty,c), B = U\cap (c,\infty)$, then $A,B$ are both open w.r.t $\mathbb{R}$ and $U \subseteq A \cup B$, and further $A \cap B = \emptyset$. This shows $U \setminus \{c\}$ is disconnected.